# ggplot chart with two different y-axes scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create a chart for this data.

```r
head(df)
x  p_values        low       upp tot_n
1  2 0.1880333 0.06039434 0.3156723    36
2  4 0.2064346 0.11294474 0.2999244    72
3  6 0.1762433 0.10438251 0.2481041   108
4  8 0.1821547 0.11911376 0.2451956   144
5 10 0.1742611 0.11884531 0.2296769   180
6 12 0.1735897 0.12307923 0.2241001   216
```

I want to represent both confidence intervals and the values of tot_n, but I'm having trouble getting two separate scales.

Here is my code:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
geom_point(aes(y = p_values), color = "blue") +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = upp, ymin = low, y = p_values)) +
geom_point(aes(y = tot_n), color = "red") +
geom_hline(yintercept = prop, linetype = "dashed", color = "red") +
scale_y_continuous(
name = "Confidence Interval",
limits = c(0, 1),
breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.2),
sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = "identity", name = "Total n", breaks = c(0, 100, 200, 300, 388))
) +
ylab("Confidence Interval") +
xlab("Sampling occasions") +
ggtitle(paste("True proportion =", prop))
```